# Spring Integration "onSuccessExpression" syntax in the advice bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a configuration class for the Spring Integration flow that has a file output channel adapter at the end of the flow. I am using ConsumerEndpointSpec.advice() to send out a notification once the file is copied. Here is my Advice bean:

```
@Bean
public Advice outboundFileCopyAdvice()
{
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnSuccessExpression("??");
    advice.setFailureChannel(fileCopySuccessChannel);
    advice.setOnFailureExpression("??");
    advice.setFailureChannel(fileCopyFailureChannel);

    return advice;
}
```

I'd like to ask what expression I should put instead of "??" to get a reference to the `Message<File>` object. I found out that I can use expressions like "payload.toString()" or "headers['someKey']", but I was not able to come up with an expression that provides a reference to the whole message object.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `#root` refers to the message object (the root object for the expression evaluation).

`payload.foo` and `headers['bar']` are shortcuts for `#root.payload.foo` (java: `message.getPayload().getFoo()`) and `#root.headers['bar']` (java: `message.getHeaders().get("bar")`).

[SpEL Documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-this-root).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gary!